# HTML - PDF Builder in CRM system - Need to inline style to google fonts, no css

Tags: html

So I'm in the process of building for brochures/reports in our CRM system which has the capacity of merging data stored agains our current listings to a html pdf builder, similar data is used as merge fields for email and letters etc.  The user can really only create blocks that are then coded to merge to a predefined field fro the CRM.
There are limitations that I'm trying to work safely around.  Fonts are an issue.  The pdf builder does not allow the user to access the  or anything like that, also there is no accessible css that I can find.  The accessible blocks of html seem only to support The only fonts it allows are the basics, times new roman, helvetica etc.
I want to be able to inline <span style= ...  to a google font  is this even possible??
Please help, want to make sure my brochures are inline with the corporate style guide and they are requesting I use Google Font Poppins.
Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use in-page styling see

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans serif;
        font-size: 48px;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
    <div style="font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;">Yours sin-serif-ly</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

produces
[image]